# add custom block just below media view more on product detail page

Tags: product, media

i want to add custom block just below media view more on product detail page, see below image :http://159.8.132.20/Untitled2.png

i want to do it vai admin > category layout update or via mdoule :

below is my code:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="test" template="handtryon/a.phtml" after="product.info.media"></block>
</reference>
```

no i am able to see contents of a.phtml on product detail page but it show below product tabs i want it below media view more i think something to do with  after="product.info.media"

Answer (score 1):

You `can not manage` **product** page layout from `admin > category layout update.`

and can only manage `from this admin>catalog>Manage Product> Custom design` tab.

As per as default magento,you need add code `<?php echo $this->getChildhtml('test')?>` at view.phtml because of all template  at view do not render automatically.

Also,you need to change `reference` name from `content` to `product.info`

Comment: no i am able to see contents of a.phtml on product detail page but it show below product tabs i want it below media view more i think something to do with  after="product.info.media"

Comment: yeah but my content shows from my above method

Comment: cannot understand